# How to use useSWRMutation with a dynamic URL?

Tags: swr

Let's say I have a component that needs to send a request when a button is clicked

```js
function Component() {
   function handleClick () {
      // Send request
   }

   return (
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
   )
}
```

I want to use [`useSWRMutation`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#useswrmutation) to send a `POST` request to the server (e.g. `POST /api/clicks/:clickId`)

```js
async function sendClick (url, { arg }) {
  await fetch(url, { // Question 1: Should it be like `${url}/${arg.clickId}`?
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(arg)
  });
}

function Component() {
   const { trigger } = useSWRMutation('/api/clicks/', sendClick); // Question 2: What URL (key) should be here? 1) /api/clicks/:clickId 2) /api/clicks 3) Nothing?

   function handleClick () {
      trigger({ id: "clickId", otherData: [] });
   }

   return (
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
   )
}
```

What key should we use in `useSWRMutation` when sending a request with dynamic URL (e.g. `/api/clicks/:clickId`)?

P.S. I have feeling that I don't need to use `useSWRMutation` hook here as soon as I don't need to cache or invalidate the cache after. The only reason why I'm using it is `isLoading` (or `isMutating`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you can:

1. Use state to store the parameter (if its useful somewhere else)
2. Pass the parameter in the payload
3. Pass the parameter in the key

Below is a demo of the three approaches.

Your choice of key depends on what you want to cache / dedupe. In this case I think a key of `[url, clickId]` makes sense.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import useSWRMutation from "swr/mutation";


function Component1() {
    const [id, setId] = useState("clickId");

    async function sendClick(url, {arg}) {
        const data = await fetch(url[0] + id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(arg)
        });
        const res = await data.json();
        console.log("Api called with url " + res.url);
    }

    const {trigger} = useSWRMutation(['https://httpbin.org/anything/api/clicks/', id], sendClick);

    function handleClick() {
        setId("clickId");
        trigger({data: "foo"});
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me 1</button>
    );
}

function Component2() {
    async function sendClick(url, {arg}) {
        const data = await fetch(url[0] + arg.id, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(arg)
        });
        const res = await data.json();
        console.log("Api called with url " + res.url);
    }

    const id = "clickId"; // get this from somewhere...
    const {trigger} = useSWRMutation(['https://httpbin.org/anything/api/clicks/', id], sendClick);

    function handleClick() {
        trigger({id: "clickId", data: "foo"});
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me 2</button>
    );
}

function Component3() {
    async function sendClick(url, {arg}) {
        const data = await fetch(url[0] + url[1], {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(arg)
        });
        const res = await data.json();
        console.log("Api called with url " + res.url);
    }

    const id = "clickId"; // get this from somewhere...
    const {trigger} = useSWRMutation(['https://httpbin.org/anything/api/clicks/', id], sendClick);

    function handleClick() {
        trigger({data: "foo"});
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me 3</button>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Component1/>
            <Component2/>
            <Component3/>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```